# LibGDX Textfield - Text Overflow - Not Wrapping

Tags: android, libgdx, gui

[image]

In my app's registration screen, the textfield is not wrapping text as I expected. Notice in the above image, the email field is not containing the text. I have set the size of the textfield using `setSize()` method but I couldn't find any way to wrap text. Is there any solution to this?

I'm using LibGDX v1.9.0.

**EDIT:** I don't have problem with overflowing but I think it should be hidden beyond the textfield borders.

**UPDATE:** It was indeed carelessness from my part. I actually included a padding to the textfield position which I didn't correct when defining its size. Issue got solved now. I don't know whether I should keep the question or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The **libGDX** `TextField` is, according tho the [API specification](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.html), a "*A single-line text input field.*".

That's why it's not wrapping the text.

Comment: Okay but still the text should be behind the borders of the textfield, you know? How can I make it that possible?

Comment: @BlackPanda Can you show more of your layout code? `TextField` will scroll the text inside its bounds if more text that can be showed is inputted so it looks like it's your layout that's the problem here.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/iVJVi8WS The text is indeed scrolling, but it is visible outside the bounds.

Comment: @BlackPanda Try turning on debug rendering on the `Stage` or some of the `Actor`'s by calling `setDebug(true)`,  that should give you an indication of what part of your layout is broken.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, but it was indeed carelessness from my part. I actually included a padding to the textfield position which I didn't correct when defining its size. Issue got solved now.

Comment: @BlackPanda Not a problem, glad you found the solution.